# after printJS printer dialog opens need to trigger print button

Tags: printjs

PrintJS working fine with pdf and printer dialog opening. but my request is once the printer dialog open need to check Destination printer is selected then i should able to trigger print button. please help on this as earlier as possible

Answer (score 1):

We can't bypass the browser dialog with JavaScript alone. This is for security reasons.

Think if you open an unknown website, if the browser didn't show you this screen, the website could potentially start sending lots of unwanted print jobs directly to your printer. Not a fun scenario :)